# How to build Makefile in Python Windows

Tags: python, winforms, makefile

I have downloaded a python demo from Github. In the README file it says-

> You'll need to build:
>   python-emd-master/: just go into the directory and type make

I tried the following in cygwin-

```
cd ~/python-emd-master
make
```

It threw below error-

> make: python2-config: Command not found
>
> > > Building object file 'emd.o'.
> > >           cc -o emd.o -c emd.c -fPIC
> > >       make: cc: Command not found
> > >       Makefile:45: recipe for target 'emd.o' failed
> > >       make: *** [emd.o] Error 127

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: `make` is required to build. It's a POSIX tool and available on most UNIX like systems. There are adoptions of POSIX build environments for windows like in cygwin but don't expect things too work smoothly.

Comment: @KlausD. thanks for the clue. Would it possible for you to tell me how to do it?

Comment: That would be too broad for SO, but you have the keywords now, try Google.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for your help. I installed cygwin with make in devel category. I change the directory to that folder and typed make. It threw this error make: python2-config: Command not found
>>> Building object file 'emd.o'.
    cc -o emd.o -c emd.c -fPIC
make: cc: Command not found
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'emd.o' failed
make: *** [emd.o] Error 127